# How to convert SoapResponse to pojos(Java classes) and Class Objects to Soap Request

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, soap-client, saaj

I want to read Soap response - how can i convert soap response to pojos(Class objects)
Also i want to send soap post request - how can i convert class objects to soap request.

I need both ways, can you please help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to marshal and unmarshal a SOAP message to POJOs, you can use [xjc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/xjc.html) to generate JAXB bindings from the schema [`https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/`](https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/).

However SOAP is not usually unmarshaled using JAXB, but through a specialized framework: [SOAP with Attachments API for Java](https://javaee.github.io/metro-saaj/). This framework can also unmarshal SOAPs with attachments: it's a `multipart/related` MIME document with an XML SOAP message and a series of attachments.

To deserialize using SAAJ you use a `MessageFactory` and provide the MIME headers of the message and an input stream:

```java
final InputStream is = ...;
final MimeHeaders mimeHeaders = ...;
final SOAPMessage soap = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(mimeHeaders, is);
```

If you have `SOAPMessage`, you can access the parts you are interested in through `getSOAPPart`, `getSOAPBody`, `getSOAPHeader` which return you DOM interfaces, which you can transform to POJOs using JAXB.

To serialize you just have to create a new `SOAPMessage`, fill it and call the `writeTo` method:

```java
final SOAPMessage soap = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
... // fill the message
final OutputStream os = ...;
soap.writeTo(os);
```